# Graph Neural Network for “Classification” - The right approach?

Tags: neural-networks, python

## Problem statement

#### System

- System(Level 1) of systems(Level 2) of systems (Level 3) (hierarchical, maximum 3 Levels)

  - Level 1 describes the entire system which is composed by some systems (let's say 1-5)
  - Level 2 can be composed by multiple subsystems (Level 3)
  - The minor level systems (Level 3) are described by a feature vector **X** and can be described in various ways **Z** which I simplified to integers: 0-5
- The entire structure leads to multiple output values. My approach is to summarize the output value to a point system from 0 to 10 where 0 means bad quality and 10 means good quality : Result Value **Y**

#### Data

- I guessed that a Graph representation is describing the problem quite well so..
- I have a set of trainings data

  - *M* different graphs including feature vectors **N** and representations **Z** for each node and the system output value **Y**

#### Objective

- Given a new graph including feature vectors **N** and representations **Z**, I want to predict the quality of the system (give points from 0 to 10)

#### Schematic Depiction

[image: Schematic Depiction]

The exemplary grayscale rows at the bubbles depict the feature vectors (N) , the numbers in the node represent the representations (Z)

## Question(s)

I am not a Computer Science Professional nor a DL/ML expert. However, I did pass some online courses for ML/DL tasks. The topic of GNN seems to be over the top of these courses, so I havent heard of them and only slowly starting in GNNs.
So:

- Do you think GNN is the correct approach for this problem or this type of data structure?
- I cant find any simple tutorial on how to use GNN for this purpose. Any recommendations or advices or hints?
- What is the best way to introduce the representation **Z** to the data? Straightforward would be to add another column to the feature vector which contains **Z**, but in my opinion that doesnt sound quite smart.